# Can a particle experience tunneling even if its energy is higher than the barrier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

I know that quantum tunneling can make particle go through the barrier even when its energy is not enough, but dose it happen when the particle's energy is higher than the barrier? Will it go through by classical way or still can go through by tunneling? If it will, what's the differences? And what make it go through by tunneling but not classical way?

Comment: relevant with figure http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html

Answer (score 1):

> I know that quantum tunneling can make particle go through the barrier even when its energy is not enough, but dose [sic] it happen when the particle's energy is higher than the barrier?
> Will it go through by classical way or still can go through by tunneling?

By definition, we usually only refer to "tunneling" when the energy of the particle/wave is smaller than the energy of the barrier.

> If it will, what's [sic] the differences? And what make it go through by tunneling but not classical way?

"Classical way" doesn't really make sense when we are taking about a particle that is described by a wave solution to the Schrodinger equation. Such a description is not classical.

But, yes, the particle will still be able to pass the barrier. It's just not as interesting since it would also be expected classically.